# Same VM image on different Azure machines

Tags: azure

I would like to install Windows 08 on two-cores machine called D2, install all necessary software, save it as an image.

Then I would like to use this image to start a new VM on six cores machine with Infiniband, called A8/A9.

Will it work?

Comment: could you answer ? it works as you indicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving it as an image, and then use this image with another VM size will work.

Even without imaging you can change the VM size, and after a reboot it will use the new VM size